# filter-name element is missing in generated web.xml

Tags: weblogic-10.x, struts-1, java-6, ejb-2.x

One of our old applications uses `Struts-1.2` and `EJB-2`, generated with `xdoclet 1.2.3`. `Maven 1` is used to build the application using `java 1.4`. The application has been running in `weblogic 8.1` without any issues.

Now we are upgrading to `Weblogic 10.3.6` which runs on `java 6`. When the application is deployed to `Weblogic 10.3.6` we encounter the following error.

```
The error is weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND problem: 
cvc-minLength-valid.1.1: string length (0) is less than minLength facet (1) for filter-nameType 
in namespace http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
```

I understand this error is because the `web.xml` file is missing the `filter-name` element for a Filter class.

The problem is `web.xml` is generated by the application as part of the build process and I have no idea where or how to add the `filter-name` element value. What should I do to get the `filter-name` element to be added to the generated `web.xml`?

(Note: There is no problem when deployed to `Weblogic8.1`. This happens only when trying to deploy on `weblogic10.3.6`.)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it going.

I had to add the following annotation to the filter class...

```
@web.filter name="FilterClassName"
```

`web.xml` generated the filter-name element after I added the above annotation.